# Account invoice report tax table

Tags: html, css, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

i have costume model that add some fields to invoice report , but i need to move up tax table up.do i need to delete rows. 
is it done by doing something like this?

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='row mt32 mb32']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="class">row mt8 mb8</attribute>
            </xpath>
```

[image]

**EDITED:**
i'm extending Account invoice report addons/account/report_invoice.xml bellow is the table that i want to move up. i can't past all report here as it is to big.

**EDIT2**
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml link to original report. i want to move up tax table along side subtotal table. :)

```
   <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Subtotal</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <t t-foreach="o._get_tax_amount_by_group()" t-as="amount_by_group">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span t-esc="amount_by_group[0]"/></td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[1]"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                 <span t-field="o.amount_total" t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" t-if="o.tax_line_ids">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Tax</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Base</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr t-foreach="o.tax_line_ids" t-as="t">
                                <td><span t-field="t.name"/></td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-field="t.base"
                                        t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-field="t.amount"
                                        t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You should add the original QWeb/HTML code of the invoice document template. Nobody can answer without that information.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Much better! But you should add the totals table (which will be right), too ;-) And a link like [invoice report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml) could help, too.

Comment: Thanx for the tips, learning step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using following way :

Add tax table before total section and remove existing one.

```
<template id="account_invoice_report_document_tax_table_ept" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
    <xpath expr="//div[@t-if='o.tax_line_ids']" position="replace">
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='col-xs-4 pull-right']" position="before">
        <div t-if="o.tax_line_ids">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tax</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Base</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr t-foreach="o.tax_line_ids" t-as="t">
                        <td><span t-field="t.name"/></td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-field="t.base"
                                t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-field="t.amount"
                                t-field-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": "o.currency_id"}'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xpath> 
</template>
```

This may help you.